# Yaml error - mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to use a yaml file but whenever I try to read from it I get:

```
 Exception in thread "main" mapping values are not allowed here in "<reader>", line 7, column 19
```

The yaml file:

```
topology:
- name: teststormsignals
  jar: storm-signals-0.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  topologyclass: backtype.storm.contrib.signals.test.SignalTopology
  packaging: mvn package
  repository: https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals.git
```

I ran it through a yaml parser but it says it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (double quoted):

```
repository: "https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals.git"
```